# Is there any method to set nodeselector for pod using golang api

Tags: go, kubernetes, nodeselector

Basically need a way to set nodeselector for Pod using GoLang API

***Pod.Spec.NodeSelector["failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone"] = zone*** is giving out error

Comment: please add more details about your source code, which Golang APi, which libs are you importing ?... so on

Comment: using golang API corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize the map before setting it. something like this

```
pod.Spec.NodeSelector = make(map[string]string)
pod.Spec.NodeSelector["failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone"] = "zone1"
```